# How to hide specific User activity options in the frontend only?

Tags: user, acl, front-end, profile

I want to hide the options "Send notifications for User Actions Log" and "Select events to be notified for Articles" (not disable them completely) in the **admin's "edit profile frontend**."

It seems that there isn't an option in joomla's menu. I tried to find the option in the com_users folder, but I can't find it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for joining us, please take our [tour].

Comment: There is no such option.

Comment: Yeah,. I think too. So I would comment out the line in the joomla source code. But I can´t find in which .php file it is.

Answer (score 0):

Template override. That's my go-to with this sort of thing. You can then target a specific user group/user to see/not see it

Comment: Thanks for you answer. And in which file do I find this option to make an override?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this in Joomla 5, and there is no specific class marking that block, so hiding it through CSS is tricky either because the number of block is dynamic. I decided use JavaScript approach by doing a template override for com_users > profile > edit.php and adding this line:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var fieldsets = document.querySelectorAll('#member-profile fieldset');

    // Checking the total number of fieldsets
    if (fieldsets.length > 2) {
      // If there are more than 2 fieldsets, hide the 2nd
      fieldsets[1].style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
</script>
```

Alternatively, you might add this inline CSS, showing it only when the page is accessed by an admin:

```
fieldset {
  &:nth-child(2) {
    display: none!important;
  }
}
```